# Debian crashes after installation

Tags: linux, installation, crash, debian, freeze

After installing Debian 12 when I first login it crashes and automatically reboots in about 3 seconds. This happens whether I use the common ISO file or the edu ISO file.
My hardware:
laptop model - victus 16
CPU -  AMD Ryzen 5 5600H
GPU - NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop
bit depth - x64
RAM - 16GB

I can not use Debian

Comment: Hi there. You should probably post this in the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) exchange. But you'll need to give a few more details. For examlple, does this happen during boot, on the login page, after login...?